# SQL like button

Tags: mysql

So, I want to make an app that uses a voting system kinda like the like button on FB or the +1 button on Google.  The one problem is that I have no idea how to design the database such that each of a large number of things has likes and dislikes from every user since it would be inefficient for each page that can be liked or disliked to have a like/dislike column for each user or for each user to have a like/dislike column for each page.  How do I make the MySQL database process likes and dislikes?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating multiple columns, you can use a *link table*:

### user table

```
user_id | user_name
--------+----------
1       | alice
2       | bob
3       | charlie
```

### page table

```
page_id | page_title
--------+--------------
1       | books
2       | food
3       | entertainment
```

### user-page link table

```
user_id | page_id
--------+--------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 3
3       | 3
```

The link table associates `user_id` values with `page_id` values. Note that one user can like more than one page, and one page can be liked by more than one user.